# Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, runtime-error, port

i use this code for working with Port

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

but I get the following error.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

[image]

Should I not connect(bind) the socket to the port?

Comment: Please post **your** code. I'm sure you don't connect to `host.contoso.com` and the example does not mention any Form either. We cannot help you without looking at the code that is actually running.

Comment: Have you started the server at the relevent IP/Port? It would be better to post actual code, rather than a link. As an aside please do not post IP/Port number on public site. This could be used by anyone outside for malicious purposes

Comment: That means either: 1. Nothing is listening on port 65352 on 192.168.0.12, or 2. A firewall stopped the request from getting to the other computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have to check whether the Database service or particular service is started or Dead position
by using this command in linux terminal

1. ## service database status  (or)  service service-name status

If particular service status is Dead or inactive then we have to start the service by using

2. ## service service-name start

Then check the connection, it will connect Absolutely

Answer (score 0):

i changd code.

```
  Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(200);
```

worked.But I didn't understand why I had to do this?

There is no such thing in Microsoft's code.